# Bidirectional Synchronization between Compact and SQL Server DB in Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

I followed the link **http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2008/12/08/building-a-sync-services-for-ado-net-solution-for-mobile-devices.aspx**

and was able to sync DB.

**Problem** is that it is only for static connection string and Server IP where SQL server DB is located which i provided through designer wizard.
   now i want to change the connection string and Server IP as provided in some file.So that user can change the Server DB location and synchronize.I don't know how to proceed.Please Help

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial the MiddleTierServiceLibrary project has an App.Config file with the DB connection string. You can set the DB connection there.